# When I boot, I can't select Ubuntu

Tags: boot

Boot problem!  It is stuck on Windows as the default.  Arrow key will not let me select.  Tried arrow keypad as well as arrow keys on the numeric keypad.  Help!

Comment: Try PgUp/PgDn. How is the keyboard connected to the computer?

Comment: Go to Bios and select USB keyboard Controlled by BIOS and not by OS as is the default choice.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would probably boot a live CD/USB and

> grub-install /dev/sda   (or whatever your boot partition is)

This should re-install grub.

You may also want to check BIOS to see that USB is enabled, which is probably why "Brandon" is asking the question.

Good Luck
Mal